# How to pass ID from "tr onclick" Url.Action method to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm trying to have a table with rows which displays a list of blogs with IDs in the left column. I want to then click a highlighted row and it will redirect you to a view with blog content corresponding to that `ID`.

So, my question is how to do you pass the `Id` (from view) when clicking on row to the `Display` action?

BlogController.cs

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{     
    var Result = from b in _db.blog
                 join aspu in _db.Users on b.userID equals aspu.Id
                 select new BlogViewModel { 
                     blogID = b.blogID, 
                     blogTitle = b.blogTitle, 
                     firstName = aspu.firstName, 
                     lastName = aspu.lastName, };

    return View(Result);
}

public IActionResult Display(int blogid)
{
    return View();
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
  <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Blog Title</th>
                <th scope="col">Date Created</th>
                <th scope="col">Author</th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="sortable" style="cursor:pointer;">
            @foreach (var v in Model)
            {  
                <!-- below line when highlight row and click it, it passes the ID in that row to the display IActionResult-->
                <tr onclick="location.href = '@(Url.Action("Display", "Blog", new { @Id = v.blogID }))'">
                    <td>@v.blogID</td>
                    <td>@v.blogTitle</td>
                    <td>@v.publishedDate</td>
                    <td>@(v.firstName + " " + v.lastName)</td>
                    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Post", new { @Id = v.blogID })</td>
                    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Post", new { @Id = v.blogID })</td>
                    @*<td><partial name="_DisplayEmployeePartial" model="v"></td>*@

                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the same parameter name in the `<tr>` tag to `BlogId` as it used in the action method:

```
 <tr onclick="location.href = '@(Url.Action("Display", "Blog", new { @BlogId = v.blogID }))'">
```

By the way, you don't need to use `@` character before the `BlogId` when you are creating the anonymous type here. See [Introduction to ASP.NET Web Programming Using the Razor Syntax (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c)